# Problem with loading CSS files in Webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-style-loader, css-loader

This is now the second day I'm trying to figure out what I've might done wrong. So far, I've followed different tutorials, reading through Webpack documentation, tried to reinstall style-loader and css-loader and even started a setup on a different machine. No luck!

Here is the error appearing every time I start webpack bundle:

```
ERROR in ./src/style.css 1:5
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:5)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> body {
|   background: green;
| }
 @ ./src/index.js 2:0-21
```

I'm thinking it might be something within my configuration, when I delete "module", I'm getting the same message:

```
const path = require("path");

module.export = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
        filename: "main.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    },
    module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

I've also installed all dependancies:

```
{
  "name": "Timer",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack --config=webpack.config.js --mode=development"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^4.2.1",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "webpack": "^4.44.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.19"
  }
}
```

I'm new at this, so I don't know where to go from here...

Comment: can you try please to require the .css with inline loaders just to see if the problem is with the webpack config?
like this:
`require('style-loader!css-loader!./src/style.css')`

Comment: That actually helped me.After testing your solution, I realised that the problem must be in webpack.config.js, and it was! If you look at my code it says "module.export" instead of "module.exports"

Comment: Great :) lets post it as answer so others could benefit it also

Answer (score 1):

Like you mentioned in your comment:

Change `module.export` to `module.exports`.